# How to create a Gradle Task

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to create a gradle task to perform below things -

- Launches the Google Cloud Engine local development server
- Runs all tests  Shuts the
- Server down again

There are seperate tasks already defined but i want to know how to combine all of three of them into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a new task that calls all of those existing tasks in order.

```
task taskA() << {
    println "I'm taskA"
}

task taskB() << {
    println "I'm taskB"
}

task taskC() << {
    println "I'm taskC"
}

task taskAll(dependsOn:['taskA', 'taskB', 'taskC']) << {
    println 'All Done!'
}
taskB.mustRunAfter  'taskA' //these lines ensure the order of execution
taskC.mustRunAfter  'taskB'
```

This gives you the output:

```
gradle taskall
:taskA
I'm taskA
:taskB
I'm taskB
:taskC
I'm taskC
:taskAll
All Done!

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.176 secs
```